# If $R[s], R[t]$ are finitely generated as $R$-modules, the so is $R[s + t]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> Let $S \supset R$ as rings with $1 \in R$.  Suppose that $s, t \in S$ and that the subrings $R[s], R[t]$ are finitely generated by $\{1, s, \dots, s^k\}$ and $\{1, t, \dots, t^m \}$.  Then $R[s + t]$ is also finitely generated.

Let $g$ be a minimal degree monic polynomial for $s$ over $R$.

I'm thinking let $f(X) = X  + t. \ $  Then $s + t = f(s). \ $  So  $f(X)^n = q(X) g(X) + r(X)$ by the division algo, where $r(X) = 0$ or $\deg{r} \lt \deg{g}$.  Then $f(s)^n = (s+t)^n = 0 + r(s), \ $ for some $r(X) \in R[t][X]$.

Now I'm very confused, but this looks like the right direction. Please work within it if you can, but all answers accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: $s,t$ are integral, and it is well-known that the sum of two integral elements is integral. See Atiyah-Macdonald, Cor 5.3

Comment: Do you have a link to that book?! @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: Go and find it in a library. It's a must-read!

Comment: ... and sadly hard to find otherwise. Someone needs to do a reprint.

Comment: Well I found a link for everybody: http://carlossicoli.free.fr/A/Atiyah_M.F.,_Macdonald_I.G..-Introduction_to_commutative_algebra%281969%29%28K%29%28T%29%28137s%29.djvu  Noobs

Comment: Although it is sad that Atiyah-Macdonald is out of print, hard to find, and outrageously expensive, I still don't think it is good idea to post a link to it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary approach is to prove $R[s]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module if and only if $s$ is integral over $R$ and that the elements of $S$ that are integral over $R$ form a subring of $S$. (See, for instance, Atiyah-Macdonald 5.1, 5.3 or Eisenbud 4.2, 4.6).

This settles your problem: $s$ and $t$ are integral over $R$ and since the integral elements of $S$ over $R$ form a ring, so is $s + t$, which shows $R[s+t]$ is finitely generated.

The proof of these results rests on the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem and, in the words of David Eisenbud, "It would be natural to prove [these results] by starting with the equations satisfied by two integral elements and simply writing down the equations satisfied by their sum and product. In a sense this is what we shall do. But in general the necessary polynomials are complicated. The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem gives them implicitly."

**Edit.** Let me at least quote the crucial theorem (Atiyah-Macdonald 5.1; Eisenbud 4.6); the formulation is more-or-less that from Atiyah-Macdonald.

**Theorem.** Let $S$ be an $R$-algebra and $s \in S$. Then the following four statements are equivalent:

1. $s$ is integral over $R$;
2. $R[s]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module;
3. $R[s]$ is contained in a subring $T$ of $S$ such that $T$ is a finitely generated $R$-module;
4. there exists a faithful $R[x]$-module $M$ which is finitely generated as an $R$-module. (Faithful means that no non-zero element of $R[x]$ annihilates $M$.)

The crucial implication is $4 \rightarrow 1$, which uses Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: I often skip proofs but this one I want to see the mechanics of.

Comment: What book are you using to study this? These results are probably in every book on commutative algebra. If you care to search, search for "Cayley-Hamilton and integral dependence". By the way, are you familiar with the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem; if someone, maybe me, would care to write down a proof, it helps to know if we could assume that.

Comment: Please see my proof below.  If my general proof method doesn't work then I'll check your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let $R[s]$ be fin-gen with monic $f$ and $R[t]$ fin-gen with monic $g$.

$(X + t)^k, k \geq 1$, is a polynomial in $R[t][X]$ .  Since $s$ is integral over $R$ with $f$ it's also integral over $R[t]$ with $f$ since $R \subset R[t]$.  Then $(X + t)^k = q(X) f(X) + r(X)$ for some $r = 0$ or $\deg r \lt \deg f$.  This means that if $h(X) = (X + t)^k$, then $h(s) = (s + t)^k$ and $h(s) = r(s)$ for some $r$.  So we have that $p \in R[s+t]$ can be expressed as $p = p_0 + p_1 (s+t) + \dots p_n (s+t)^n = p_0 + p_1 r_1(s, t) + \dots + p_n r_n(s,t)$, each $r_i$ having degree $\leq \deg f + \deg g$, and each of which is a polynomial in $\{s^{i}t^{j} : 0 \leq i,j, i+j \leq \deg f + \deg g \} $.  This set is finite and clearly generates $R[s + t]$ over $R$ as an $R$-module.

**QED**

Comment: Seems ok, although your proof would benefit from some cleanup to help the reader. I believe, though, that Cayley-Hamilton is typically used to go from $R[s]$ is finitely generated to $s$ is integral. You use this right away, already in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not so sure it looks ok anymore. The $s^i t^j$ don't have to be in $R[s + t]$, so they can't generate it.